# Вопрос по оформлению - отлова ошибок - избежание вылетов

Tags: c#, исключения, обработка-ошибок

Кодинг не профессия и поэтому не читал и не смотрел как и кто что то оформляет - делает. Просто хобби - понимаю что делают переменные и всякие условия, а различные библиотеки можно посмотреть - что делают там классы - методы и т.д.

А тут попросили кое что на сторону сделать впервые! - не для себя и стал задумываться xD
Так вот вопрос - это нормально вот так избегать ошибки) - оформлять ? или это отврат ? или забить на эти моменты и делать чтобы главное работало ?

```
// Отлов элемента по xpatch и клик по элементу c помощью JS | True - клик удался | False - клик не удался 
private bool clickOnInvisibleElement(string xpath, IWebDriver Browser)
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait ss = new WebDriverWait(Browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement elem = ss.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(xpath)));

        String script = "var object = arguments[0];"
                + "var theEvent = document.createEvent(\"MouseEvent\");"
                + "theEvent.initMouseEvent(\"click\", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);"
                + "object.dispatchEvent(theEvent);"
                ;

        IJavaScriptExecutor jsDriver = Browser as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        jsDriver.ExecuteScript(script, elem);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Подобным вы просто глушите ошибки, не говоря другому разработчику что именно не так и почему код все же вернул false.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В данном случае если false - то с помощью goto я просто повторяю отрезок.
Правильно будет записать ошибку в log и если надо повторить отрезок - то повторять ? А вот то что так комментирую метод - это пойдёт) ?

Comment: А имеет ли смысл повторять? Если у вас `Browser == null`, то какой смысл от повторения?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ну я полагаю что тут ошибка вылезет только в случае недоступности сайта / элемента.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov как тогда правильно делать ? Можно коротко ? Некогда просто книги читать(

Comment: Тогда нужно анализировать какая именно была ошибка и повторять только в этом случае. И то вопрос. А вдруг у вас ошибка в xpath

Comment: @AntonShchyrov блин - строение сайта же может поменяться и будет реально тогда в xpath - а это надо знать!

Comment: Разделите этот код на несколько частей и отдавайте обратно Exeption, если в нем что то не так. Например у вас эти параметры `string xpath, IWebDriver Browser` пользователь передаст пустые/NULL, дальше же не сработает код, верно? Отдавайте в ответ пользователю например `ArgumentNullException` если они равны null и пусть другой программист видит сам где он накосячил.  Так делайте и в других местах (если конечно эту ошибку нельзя допустить и обработать на вашей стороне).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ программист должен заранее предугадывать какие ошибки могут быть и  обрабатывать заранее или можно Exception отлавливать ZapisiVLog(ex.Message); на большой кусок кода и потом думать уже что с этим делать. Просто у меня нет знаний и понятия откуда я могу узнать - какая из строчек в методе - может выдать или не выдать Exception

Comment: Библиотеки не пишут в лог, это делает по необходимости пользователь этой библиотеки. Если вы пишете для кого то код (библиотеку например), то будьте добры сделать ее как можно информативней для своих пользователей. Сейчас у вас есть много мест, где этот код может упасть, пользователю придет только `bool` значение и он совершенно не будет знать из за чего такое произошло. Вдруг сайт упал, XPath неверный, передал пустые объекты, сайт дизайн сменил и куча чего еще - это все ошибки о которых он должен знать, а вы ему просто, `false`...

Comment: Что касается `программист должен заранее предугадывать какие ошибки могут быть` - для этого есть [комментарии](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/exception), с помощью которых пользователь узнает из за чего может произойти та или иная ошибка. Можете вовсе написать свою документацию, где распишете подробнее о том, что делает ваш код.

Answer (score 2):

Такой отлов ошибки это одна из самых плохих вещей, которые можно придумать. Хуже только так

```
private void clickOnInvisibleElement(string xpath, IWebDriver Browser)
{
    try
    {
        .............
        IJavaScriptExecutor jsDriver = Browser as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        jsDriver.ExecuteScript(script, elem);
    }
    catch (Exception) {}
}
```

вы теряете всю информацию об ошибке. Если вы можете корректно обработать исключение, вы его обрабатываете. Если нет, то пусть обрабатывает вызывающий код.

Иначе у вас возникнет ситуация, когда программа не работает и непонятно почему.

Comment: Вооо) раньше делал именно так - расту xD А как тогда правильно делать ?

Comment: @Vipz как правильно я написал. Ожидаемые ошибки обрабатывать, неожидаемые отдавать выше